# Progress Dialog not showing during UI task

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am writing an Android app that needs to list all the Active and Disabled packages. I'd like to show a progress dialog because it takes a while, and I don't want to keep the screen "hung" while the process completes.

This is the important snippet:

```
    pm = getPackageManager();

    ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait", "Loading Packages...");

    pkgsEn = PackageLister.retrievePackageList(pm, getResources(), PackageLister.PACKAGES_ENABLED);
    pkgsDis = PackageLister.retrievePackageList(pm, getResources(), PackageLister.PACKAGES_DISABLED);

    laEn = new PackageAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.packageinfo, pkgsEn);
    laDis = new PackageAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.packageinfo, pkgsDis);

    lvEn = new ListView(getBaseContext());
    lvDis = new ListView(getBaseContext());

    pd.dismiss();
```

There's no error message, it just freezes the screen until the listing is completed.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the show() on the progress dialog does not instantly show it. You need to retrieve your package list in a loader or asynctask and then dismiss your progress dialog after that background work is done. Doing all the work sequentially on the main thread wont allow for the dialog to be shown.